# How to add custom SQL alias for "SELECT * FROM" query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to add a custom PostgreSQL alias for query that displays whole table content? I use it so often and I would like to write istead of

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ
```

something shorter and faster, like: `**XYZ`

Where operator `**` would be my custom alias for `SELECT * FROM` statement.
Is there a way to add it to postgresql?

Comment: You don't usually retrieve whole tables, so that query is not that useful. Unless of course, you are typing on an interactve query tool while developing or debugging an app. If that's the case, then your tool could provide those aliases for you, not the engine.

Comment: Make a macro using Auto Hot Keys or something similar.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. MySQL is not PostgreSQL, and TSQL is for MS SQL Server. Abusing tags is an excellent way to collect down votes. Tags have meaning and relevance here, and they should be used properly by only using the ones that are actually applicable to your post.

Comment: No.  Such a construct does not really exist in SQL, although some databases may have specific shortcuts.

Comment: I would use a text expander app that would actually convert to `SELECT * FROM`. Autohotkey could do this like @d0little suggested.

Comment: No. There are no "custom operators" that you can define, a select statement will require the `select clause` and in most cases also a `from clause`. Terse/brief/shortcut code isn't an aim of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQL standard conforming `TABLE`:

```
TABLE xyz;
```

Quotation from the standard:

> The <explicit table>
>
> ```
> TABLE <table or query name>
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the <query expression>
>
> ```
> ( SELECT * FROM <table or query name> )
> ```

Comment: I know this question is not for MSSQL, but I tried it there to no avail. I just wanted to see. Wondering if it would work with a `WHERE` like `TABLE xyz WHERE id = 1`. Not sure why one wouldn't just `SELECT *`

Comment: Microsoft SQL server is not particularly great about implementing the standard.

Comment: Well at least your answer is valid! I learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a `view` such as this:

```
create view myxyz as
select * from xyz
;
```

Then you can reference that view in any subsequent query, e.g.

```
select * from myxyz
```

HOWEVER

- select * is NOT automatic when used in a view i.e. if you add, remove or rename columns in the source table you need to refresh the view as well. For this reason I strongly prefer to explicitly list columns in any query including definition of a view
- defining extra db objects, just to shorten code, is not something I would recommend either

Comment: How does this help though? OP is not looking to wrap his table which still involves a `SELECT *`. Still I suppose this is useful `CREATE VIEW` example. We have many of these already though.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I didn't ask the question and personally I don't recommend creating an object for the request. However as the op wants the briefest way to give a name to some query with a name of their choosing I can't think of a better way than a view.  Can you?

Comment: Of course we all thought of this. Views are pretty basic. However, when you read the question it's clear that a view won't solve this at all. It does not help at all and the OP probably already knows about views. I'm just saying that this does not even come close to answering this question. Not that your answer isn't good. Just not here.

Comment: @MichaelZ How do you know the OP is aware of views? (afraid I don't see that anywhere)

Comment: And yes, as my comment says, a better way would be to use a text expander app to expand `**` to `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: How does a view help him?

Comment: @MichaelZ. the question specifically asks for `a custom PostgreSQL alias`  wasn't aware that a third party text expander met that requirement

Comment: if you read carefully, OP is wanting to not type `SELECT * FROM` anymore as OP types it very often. A view still requires `SELECT *`

Comment: I get it, I truly do, but as you are also aware there isn't anything native to achieve the request. View hadn't been mentioned and it should have been IMHO. Similarly it is no more wordy or useful than the use of `table` in a previous answer but you seen OK with that.

Comment: the other answer is actually much better. It uses `TABLE xyz` to do what `SELECT * FROM xyz` does. This is a valid answer to this question. I'm sorry, I just watched a newbie answer get downvoted for mentioning CTE. A CTE is as good as your View answer.